# Is it possible to find the refresh rate for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, screen

I want to know if it is possible to find the refresh rate for the iPhone screen, programmatically. I have searched, but have found no private API available.

Is there any way to find this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [UIScreen.maximumFramesPerSecond](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2806814-maximumframespersecond)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the iPhone screen refresh rate is fixed to 60Hz, but you can test this yourself using the [CADisplayLink](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) API which will call a selector you choose whenever the screen is updated

Use something like:

```
CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(update)];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: But how to display the refresh rate... means how i can show the duration details ? can you please suggest a way ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. On iOS 10.3+ you can use [UIScreen.maximumFramesPerSecond](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/2806814-maximumframespersecond) to get "The maximum number of frames per second of which the screen is capable."